# Not able to copy entity in ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, manytomanyfield

I have an Entity Class Which has ManyToMany relationship with the other class.I want to create a new entry in the table of this instance by just changing its name property.

**Employee.java`**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(String name, List<Address> address) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.setAddress(address);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.DETACH },fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_address", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "address_id") })
    private List<Address> address;

    @OneToOne
    private Department department;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address {
    public Address() {
        super();
    }

    public Address(String address) {
        super();
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String address;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "address", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Employee> employee;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

**DataRetrivalServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class DataServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
@Transactional
    public void copyEmpoyee() {
        Employee e = employeeRepo.findOneById(15);
        entityManager.detach(e);
        e.setId(0);
        e.setName("new Name");
        //employeeRepo.save(e);
        entityManager.persist(e);
    }
```

When i run the code a new entry is made in the employee table but not in the Address table. Can anyone please explain where am i doing wrong!

The Entire Code can be found at - https://github.com/iftekharkhan09/JPAHibernateProject

Comment: If I am not wrong, I would not expect a new entry in the `ADDRESS` table. There is no new address entity being created here. This is only creating a new employee (say, E2) that will be associated with the same addresses as the original employee (say, E1). I would only expect new entries in the join table, `EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS`, mapping E2's employee id to the already existing addresses' ids.